# Efficient parse query - compare objectId with pointer

Tags: android, performance, parse-platform

I have three classes in my database in Parse. In ClassA I have my objects. In ClassB I collect objects that user has put them in categoryB.
In classB I  keep the user (pointer) and also the pointer of object classA. In classC I collect objects which user has put them in categoryC. In same way in ClassC I keep user (pointer) and also the pointer of object classA. In my query I want to get all the objects from classA which don't exist neither in classB neither in classC for the current user.

I have try to use the `whereMatchesKeyInQuery` but I can't use it because I can't compare the objectId from classA with the pointer of classA of classB or classC.

Also, I could use the `whereContainedIn`. In this case I should first find the pointers of classA in classB after I should get the ids in order to be able to compare. Also I should do the same function for the classB. This doesn't be elegant neither efficient.